# Two redirection from one page

Tags: php

How to redirect to two different php pages from one single html page by clicking two different buttons?
I have two buttons say, btn1 and btn2

*If I **click btn1**, the html page page should redirect to **page1.php** with form values.

*In the same way, if I **click btn2**, the html page page should redirect to **page2.php** with form values.

```
<form action = "check.php" method = "post">
    <div align = "center">
        <table>
            <thead><h2>LOGIN FORM<h2></thead>
            <tr>
                <td><h4>Username</h4></td>
                <td><input type = "text" name = "username"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><h4>Password</h4></td>
                <td><input type = "password" name = "password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><button name = "register">Sign up</button></td>
                <td><button name = "submit">Login</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here, if I click Login I have to move to check.php and if I click Sign Up, it should be redirected to sample.php.

But in the above code, I can only redirect to one php file.

How to redirect the sign up button to another php file?

Comment: Please shre your code and describe what issues you are facing with it

Comment: it would be confusing unless you give some code snippet about how you're writing your code, is it a form or only buttons.

Comment: You can use ajax for this. Don't submit the form on button click but initiate different ajax calls on each button click. Send the form data with AJAX to your respective PHP file.

Comment: ..or have the form point to one file in action attribute. Then on the server, in that file upon receiving the form, you check which button was pressed and redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: How to check which button was clicked

Comment: @Anthony You can use name/value attributes for submit buttons as well. Then you check for - one of - those values on the server after receiving a submit. Try `print_r($_POST);` on the server and check the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can redirect to one page and add two functionalities:

As you have named the login button as submit, in the php file check whether submit is set, if yes, add the operations of login. If no, add the operations of sign up in the else part.